# Should you always lazy load Angular modules?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Me and my team are developing a fairly small application (basically just a login page that will redirect you somewhere else). We currently had the idea of having one Core module and one module with the rest of the content of the page but it seems like overkill given the fact that we will always load that module before anything is painted on the screen anyways. Would there still be a valid reason to include lazy loading or would be better off just importing the module into the AppModule directly?

I'm aware of the benefits of lazy loading but we are certain that this application will not grow much if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading helps you to reduce the size of initial bundle files and only loads more chunks if needed. In your scenario if you do not have anything to load later, you practically do not need lazy loading as it will not be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a modular architecture is important. Lazy loading will then only become a matter of some routing configurations. You can tweak whether you want to do lazy loading or not based on how quickly your app loads on the first go.

Another thought is if you are making different API calls to get some data in different modules then you might consider loading lazily. But if everything loads at once, then as I said above you can compare performance with and without lazy loading.